# Modify column in aspxgrid to display a hyper link and support group by

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a devexpress gridview that displays the UserID in a column.
I group by this column, and I want to modify the value that is displayed by adding a hyperlink to point to the user profile page.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ..>

<Columns>
..

<dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="UserID" Caption="User" VisibleIndex="2" 
  Visible="false">
  <Settings AllowSort="False" AllowDragDrop="False" />                                
</dx:GridViewDataColumn>

..
</Columns>

</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

But whenever I try to add a DataItemTemplate, it doesn't effect the output at all.

How can I modify what is displayed with a link?

Right now it shows:

```
User 12323
```

I want to display:

```
User <a href="/profile.aspx?userid=12323">12323</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code would show 12323 as a hyperlink which would take as ID and redirect to your desired page.

```
       <dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn VisibleIndex="0" Settings-FilterMode="DisplayText" Caption="User" 
                ShowInCustomizationForm="True"
             FieldName="UserID" Width="58px">
            <DataItemTemplate>
              <dx:ASPxHyperLink Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="Blue" ID="ASPxHyperLinkTest" Target="_blank" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserID") %>'
 NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("profile.aspx?userid={0}",Eval("UserID"))%>'>
        </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
      </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used a DevExpress Gridview before but if it inherits from GridView then this could work:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "User <a href=""/profile.aspx?userid=" & DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserID") & """>" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserID") + "</a>"
        End If

End Sub
```